# How to convert a stylus hash table to a mixin

Tags: stylus

I have a certain **hash table** that I want to convert to **mixins** to use.

My hash table looks like this (but bigger):

```stylus
$headings = {
  h1: {
    size: 32px,
    line-height: 32px,
    letter-spacing: normal,
    weight: $weight-bold
  },
  h2: {
    size: 20px,
    line-height: 24px,
    letter-spacing: 0.25px,
    weight: $weight-bold
  },
  h3: {
    size: 20px,
    line-height: 24px,
    letter-spacing: normal,
    weight: $weight-regular
  }
}
```

And I want to create mixins like this:

```stylus
text-h1()
  font-size $headings[h1][size]
  font-weight $headings[h1][weight]
  line-height $headings[h1][line-height]
  letter-spacing $headings[h1][letter-spacing]
```

But it's not working. Nothing shows up.
I'm not sure how I can retrieve the values to assign them to the correct css prop.

If I can just retrieve the value, I can make each mixin manually.

If there's a better approach by going through the hash table with a loop, I'm also happy to use that. But I wasn't able to create it.

Comment: Does `$headings.h1.size` work or perhaps `$headings["h1"].size`

Comment: @webnoob No, i tried those as well! Doesn't work : (